# Language syncronization in extbase repositories

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

Some of my extbase repositories need to be updated from external sources. The externally updated fields are untranslated (defined with 'l10n_mode' => 'exclude' in TCA). If I update the field inside the typo3 backend, the changes are copied to all translated records. But if I change the field in the repository and persist it with the persistence manager, then only the record in the original language is affected by the change. Did I miss some configuration to make extbase persist the changes of untranslateable fields?

The typo3 does the handling of translated records with the DataHandler. I cannot use it in my function, because the DataHandler only works in backend context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that Extbase supports next to none of the features TYPO3 itself offers through its backend editing (using the `DataHandler`). So if you need to stick to the Extbase persistence no matter what you need to implement features like this yourself.

For this reason you should consider [External Import](https://packagist.org/packages/cobweb/external_import) for import of data from external sources. Internally this package uses the `DataHandler` and thus benefits from all of its features including l10n synchronization.